# How to use file structure?

Tags: c, file, file-io, input

I am having a small problem, I have the current file structure:
[image]

***And this is my code:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char FILE_NAME[] = "inputfile.txt";

int main()
{
    FILE *in_file;    /* input file */

    in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if (in_file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
        exit(8);
    }else{
        printf("File opened %s\n", FILE_NAME);
    } 
    fclose(in_file);
    return (0);
}
```

***And I get this error:***

> Cannot open inputfile.txt

But the file is right there.
Can someone help me?

*(If I change the "r" to "w" I can write to the file, but I can't find the file on my SSD)*

Comment: Your c file is in same folder as in text file right ?

Comment: This main function is inside: ch14pexercise1.c

Comment: doesn't matter where the .c file is, he needs to check the current working directory. You can call `getcwd` to figure that out f.e.

Comment: Try with full path to file. Also check exact error code.

Comment: A book on C programming that doesn't explain how to use `perror` or `errno` seems to me to be less than practical. Just my two cents.

Comment: In the same vein, if it begins by teaching to compile with `cmake` instead of the command line, it is likewise less than practical. The gaps in understanding created lead to just this type of question...

Comment: Actually it teaches all kind of compilers, but mostly command line compilers, like gcc, but I prefer the idea, because I will have to work with it instead of command line compilers.

Answer (score 5):

The program will look for the file in the current working directory. This is most likely the same directory as the compiled executable.

If you are using an IDE, check the project settings and check where the compiled executable is placed. Then either copy the textfile to that directory manually or edit the project so that building it copies the file automatically.

If you are working from the command line (assuming your compiler is called `gcc`):

```
cd ~/Documents/programming/c/PracticalC/chapter14
gcc -Wall ch14pexercise1.c -o prog
./prog
```

Answer (score 0):

## include

## include

const char FILE_NAME[] = "inputfile.txt";

int main()
{

```
FILE *in_file;    /* write file */





in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
if (in_file == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
    exit(8);
}else{
    printf("File opened %s\n", FILE_NAME);
} 
fclose(in_file);
```

/*read file*/

```
FILE *in_file;    /* input file */





in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
if (in_file == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
    exit(8);
}else{
    printf("File opened %s\n", FILE_NAME);
} 
fclose(in_file);
return (0);
```

}

If it work cheak path